# firestore re rendering updated doc with old doc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get any docs in the messages collection and render them out. But for example. If there is 1 doc, it will display that one doc, but if I change any values of that doc it will rerender but not replace the old one, and so it creates a new element to render and doesn't delete the old unupdated one.
I have given the code below. Kindly help.

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("messages")

useEffect(() => {
let items = [];
ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    items.push(doc.data());
  });
  
  items.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item);
    document.getElementById("postDisplay").innerHTML += `
    <div class="post">
    <h1>${item.title}</h1>
    <p>${item.desc}</p>
    </div>
    `
  })


});}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your items array initialization inside `.onSnapshot()` because each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot and the new data gets pushed to the `items` array.

```js
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("messages")

useEffect(() => {
  ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

    let items = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      items.push(doc.data());
    });

    items.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      document.getElementById("postDisplay").innerHTML += `
    <div class="post">
    <h1>${item.title}</h1>
    <p>${item.desc}</p>
    </div>
    `
    })


  });
}, [])
```

Comment: nothing renders now

Comment: Try storing the data in a hook and use that hook to render your content.